# Why is this alternating summation involving reciprocals of divisors always positive? A conjecture.

Tags: solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, primorial

**Conjecture**. For all $n,m \in \Bbb{N}$,

$$
f(n, m) := \sum_{c\mid d\mid n\# \\ \gcd(c, 2m) = 1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\omega(d)}}{d}
$$

is greater than $0$.

Example verification code:

```
from sympy import *

def reciprocal_sum(n, m):
    s = 0
    for d in divisors(n):
        t = 0
        for c in divisors(d):
             if gcd(c, m) == 1:
                  t += 1/d
        s += (-1)**primeomega(d) * t
    return s

N = 30

for m in range(1, N):
     for n in range(1, N):
         n = primorial(n, nth=False)   # Note primorial of n used
         m = 2*m
         F = reciprocal_sum(n, m)
         assert(F > 0)
         print(F)
```

As you can see, the conjecture is water-tight.  How would we prove such a thing?

Note that you cannot replace $n\#$ with general $n$ as the you will get negative or $0$ values.

Also you can't change $2m$ in the $\gcd$ to just $m$ or you will likewise get negative values.  But with this combination of things, the sum always seems to be positive.

---

The code prints:

```
1.0
0.5
0.16666666666666669
0.16666666666666669
0.1
0.1
0.07142857142857151
0.07142857142857151
0.07142857142857151
0.07142857142857151
0.05844155844155851
0.05844155844155851
0.04945054945054941
0.04945054945054941
0.04945054945054941
0.04945054945054941
0.043632837750484876
0.043632837750484876
0.039039907460960095
0.039039907460960095
0.039039907460960095
0.039039907460960095
0.035645132899137504
0.035645132899137504
```

until it gets too spatially complex to compute further primorials.  Anyway, take away any of the ingredients, and this special summation fails to be always positive.

---

**Attempt**.
It's true for $\Omega(n\#) =: n' = 0$ and for all $m \in \Bbb{N}$.  *Exercise.* Prove this.

Now assume that it's true for all $0 \leq \Omega(n\#) \lt r$, then in the inductive case that $\Omega((n+i)\#) = \Omega(qn\#) = r, \ q$ some prime, we have that:

$$
f(n + i,m) = \sum_{c \mid d \mid (qn\#)\\ \gcd(c, 2m) = 1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(d)}}{d} \\ = \sum_{c \mid d \mid n\# \\ \gcd(c, 2m) = 1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(d)}}{d} + \sum_{d \mid n\#} \sum_{c \mid (qd) \\ \gcd(c, 2m) = 1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\omega(qd)}}{qd} \\ = \sum_{c \mid d \mid n\# \\ \gcd(c, 2m)=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(d)}}{d} + \sum_{d \mid n\#} \left(\sum_{c \mid d \\ \gcd(c,2m)=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(qd)}}{qd} + \sum_{c \mid d \\ \gcd(qc,2m)=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(qd)}}{qd} \right) \\ = \sum_{c \mid d \mid n\# \\ \gcd(c, 2m)=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(d)}}{d} - \dfrac{1}{q}\sum_{d \mid n\#} \left(\sum_{c \mid d \\ \gcd(c,2m)=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(d)}}{d} + \sum_{c \mid d \\ \gcd(qc,2m)=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(d)}}{d} \right)
$$

That is the previous case times a factor of $(1-\dfrac{1}{q})$ (which is always positive), minus $\dfrac{1}{q}\sum_{c \mid d \mid n\# \\ \gcd(qc, 2m) = 1} \dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(d)}}{d}$.  There are two cases: $q \mid m$ and $q \nmid m$.   When $q \mid m$ clearly, the last spoken of summation term is $0$ and we're done.  So assume that $q\nmid m$.  Then $\{c \mid d : \gcd(qc, 2m) = 1\} = \{c \mid d: \gcd(c, 2m) = 1\}$.  In which case the summation is $\dfrac{-1}{q} \times$ the previous case so that, we have the total summation is $\text{previous case} \times (1 - \dfrac{2}{q})$  which positive if and only if $1 - \dfrac{2}{q} \gt 0 \iff q \gt 2$.  If on the other hand $q = 2$, then similarly in the case above, we have a summation value of $0$ in this last summation term.

In more mathematical terms we have that:

$$
f(n, m) = \prod_{q \mid n\# \\ q \text{ prime}} \left(\begin{cases}(1 - \dfrac{1}{q}) \text{ if } \gcd(q, 2m) \neq 1 \\
(1 - \dfrac{2}{q}) \text{ if } \gcd(q, 2m) = 1 \end{cases}\right)
$$

which is always positive because if $q = 2$ then it falls to the first case, and if $q \gt 2$ then it falls to either case which will still be a positive number in the second case, since $q \gt 2$.

I think that's a QED.  Please confirm.  I started this as an attempt, but it ended in an answer.

Comment: $c$ does not appear in the sum. Typo ? Also : How far did you check this ?

Comment: @Peter good spot, that means you duplicate $1/d$ however many times you need to to accomodate that index set.  You could also rewrite this as a double summation with the $c$ stuff in the inner summation.  I've posted an update with code output.  You can only check it so far in SymPy in a limited time constraint (10 minutes).  The code was written with 2 for-loops, which reflects more the double summation I mentioned.  It's $\sum_{d \mid n\#} (-1)^{\omega(d)} \sum_{c \mid d \\ \gcd(c, 2m) = 1} \dfrac{1}{d}$

Comment: You can change the order of the test loops over possible $n, m$ and also lower $N$ to see that for other test cases, the same conclusion seems likely.

Comment: So it could be written with a single sum and set size as $$\sum_{d\mid n\#}\frac{(-1)^{\omega(d)}}{d}\cdot|\{c:c\mid d\land \gcd(c,2m)=1\}|$$right?

Comment: Note that with $n\#$ we can also write $(-1)^{\Omega(d)}$ in place of $(-1)^{\omega(d)}$.  So the Liouville function is what alternates the sum.

Comment: Never mind. I goofed a little. But "$(-1)^{\omega(d)}$ for only square-free $d$" practically screams Mobius function.

Comment: @Arthur yes, exactly!  That is the summation's value and another way of writing it! :)

Comment: Looks correct. Primorial in the final formula is unnecessary, $q \mid n\#$ could as well be just $q \leq n$.

Comment: @Sil: Thanks!  I'm wondering how we can apply this fact to the twin prime problem.  See my related, recent posts for the relationship.  For that you need to transform the floors into the equivalent expression involving a fraction over $d$ and modulus operation.